# Trigger.('click') function in document.read function is not working all the times using jquery tried all the examples but not working

Tags: jquery

I have a trigger click function which will take me to another function to fetch the data but this trigger.click which is in document.ready is not triggering all the times.

I tried all the solutions but none of them worked for me

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#imggetdata').trigger('click'); 
});
```

**Reason-** I have multiple records in grid when i am editing only particular record its happening in this way means that trigger click is not firing the function and in the same grid if i edit other records its working that means its navigating to the function

Comment: is that mean `document.ready`?

Comment: yes it is in doument.ready only

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your click event definition. maybe the click event is created after your trigger. or click event creation is run before the render the element that want to attach. or maybe errors.

Comment: actually in this $('#imggetdata').trigger('click'); event it gets navigated to another function but only in one specific case its not working that means its not navigating to the function

Comment: you mean in a single request, you do something to trigger event that is works correctly, but if on the same request, without refreshing the page , after that , you do something else , the event will not triggering? so what are you doing ,when it is ok  and not ok? i mean please explain more about what you do ?

Comment: posted the reason and scenario in my question

Comment: so you call the click trigger that is inside a document ready , all together, in a click event?

Comment: yes as of now trigger click is in  document ready only but its not working for one record in the same grid

Comment: it doesn't need to be in document ready. if you are use the trigger in another click handler , so just call the trigger without document ready.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason**

the main reason for this is your triggering event before the handler is attached to the DOM,

**solution**

Try by adding some timeout function for the trigger, so as page loads after some milliseconds the click event will get a trigger, try my below code this may help you.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
      setTimeout(function() {
        alert('button clicked');
        $('#imggetdata').trigger('click'); 
      },1000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```